# How to use @ImportResource annotation import differrent enviroment config file

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to use @ImportResource annotation import on different environment config files like reported below:

```java
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableAsync
@ImportResource(locations= {"classpath:${dev|sit}/service-applicationContext.xml","classpath:${dev|sit}/client-applicationContext.xml"})
public class DmrEsbService {
}
```

Or I'm trying to use other ways to import properties like  `spring.profiles.active=test`, as I reported below:

```java
@Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
public String env;

@Autowired
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (null == ESBClientFactory.applicationContext) {
            String[] profiles = {"/profiles/" + env + "/client-applicationContext.xml", "/profiles/" + env + "/service-applicationContext.xml"};
            ESBClientFactory.applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(profiles, applicationContext);
        }
    }
}
```

but by using this last way to startup the app, it happened like below:

```
2021-12-10 15:04:16.005 - [<init> 122] - [INFO] - To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2021-12-10 15:04:16.027 - [getInstance 281] - [INFO] - DynamicPropertyFactory is initialized with configuration sources: com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration@1fdc92b
2021-12-10 15:04:17.795 - [refresh 554] - [WARN] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'publicQueryService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.xxxx.oracle.xmlns.apps.cux.soaprovider.plsql.cux_esb_mass_query_pkg.CUXESBMASSQUERYPKGPortType' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=, name=, description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=class java.lang.Object, mappedName=)}
2021-12-10 15:04:17.810 - [log 173] - [INFO] - Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-12-10 15:04:17.917 - [logMessage 142] - [INFO] - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-12-10 15:04:17.917 - [deregister 65] - [INFO] - Unregistering application xxxx with eureka with status DOWN
2021-12-10 15:04:17.918 - [shutdown 888] - [INFO] - Shutting down DiscoveryClient ...
2021-12-10 15:04:17.925 - [shutdown 911] - [INFO] - Completed shut down of DiscoveryClient
2021-12-10 15:04:18.225 - [report 42] - [ERROR] - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

A component required a bean of type 'com.xxx.oracle.xmlns.apps.cux.soaprovider.plsql.cux_esb_mass_query_pkg.xxx' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.xxx.oracle.xmlns.apps.cux.soaprovider.plsql.cux_esb_mass_query_pkg.xxx' in your configuration.
```

I could not use the command below to package an app:

```
mvn clean -Dmaven.test.skip=true package -pl xxx -am -Psit
```

and then I'm using the following:

```
mvn clean install
```

could anyone who can tell to how to import different environment in my project?